# Understanding For loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am having little difficulty in figuring out following piece of simple for loop code in C.

```
int j=20;
for(int i=0, j; i<=j ; i++, j--)     
    printf("i = %d and j = %d \n",i,j);
```

Prints output as

```
i=0 and j=2
i=1 and j=1
```

Why it does not starts with `j=20` and rather prints `j=2` and stops after `j=1`.

But when I use this code

```
int j=20;
for(int i=0, j=20; i<=j ; i++, j--)     
    printf("i = %d and j = %d \n",i,j);
```

It starts properly with

```
i=0 and j=20 upto ... i=9 and j= 11
```

Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: ahhh... variable shadowing...

Comment: Both examples have more than one *different* variables named `j`.  AVOID this situation if you can help it.

Comment: And what's worse, the shadowing `j` is uninitialized.

Comment: @chris I think it is both times

Comment: The first clause of a `for` statement is for initialization, not declaration (though that may be a side-effect).  It's unwise to declare variables there that you do not initialize.

Comment: @AdrianCornish, Well, I've never heard of something where you can initialize an int to 2 without ever saying 2 anywhere.

Comment: Is it really C? I thought C can't declare variables in for loop?

Comment: @dpp, One of the newer ones (like C99) can IIRC.

Comment: @chris -- it's quite easy, if you initialize with garbage.

Comment: @chris Ahh now I see it - new j in for without an init value

Comment: Note that the compiler may well have produced several warning messages (such as "duplicate declaration" or "uninitialized variable") for this case.  It's wise to check those warning messages.

Comment: @A K - I do not know if this is valid C code. But if it is do not write it as it is unreadable and cannot be understand. It will bite you in the buttocks later in life if you write such code.

Comment: @All I can figure that out I need to do j=20 in the declaration, but why is it so? and why is it picking up j=2 always if I do not initialize it? Memory related issues as mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: AK -- You declared a new version of `j` in the first clause of the `for` statement, without giving it a value.  So it uses whatever value is in storage, left over from the previous method call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are. Declaring j inside of the for construct creates a new (scoped) j, which has a value different from the outer. If you fail to initialize it, you get whatever crap happened to be in memory when allocated.

Variables like this are called "automatic" variables, and are allocated on the program's stack. As you need one, more stack space is allocated. When they go out of scope (really when the function returns), they are cleaned up by popping them all back off.

When the next bit of automatic storage is needed, the same thing happens and you then get whatever bit pattern happened to be left over on the stack as your new variables value.

Comment: Of course the inner j has a value, it is just not defined by the language what it will be. Since it is allocated from the stack, it will be whatever happens to be on "top", which may in fact be very consistent for your program at the time.

Comment: @AdrianCornish -- Yes, all variables have values.  But `j`, in this case has a "value" that is whatever garbage was left in that location by the previous method call.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the first portion of the for loop you have done `int i = 0, j`. What this does is to declare a variable named `j` which has a **scope local to the for loop** . Therefore there is no relation between the `j` declared and defined before the for loop and the one which you declare and define inside the for loop scope. Referring `j` inside the loop will refer to the one which is the innermost block, therefore taking `j` initialized to zero you get the first output.

Also note that you are lucky enough that the value of `j` is zero. It is an automatic variable and is not guaranteed to be zero upon definition.

On the next loop you see the output you want because, as previously the `j` defined inside the for loop is referred, but as you have initialized the value of `j` local to the for loop with the same value of the `j` outside (which has nothing to do with the `j` inside the for loop), hence you get the second output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is the common confusion in `for` loop syntax. What happening in your case is:

```
int i=0, j; //create 2 int variables - i (which is initialized to 0) and uninitialized j
```

This looks similar to `for(i,j; i<j; i++, j--)`. However what you did - is basically created additional uninitialized variable `j`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about one-line code.
    when you type `int i=0, j;` in a line, it equals to `int i = 0; int j;`
    however, when you type `int i=0, j=20;`, it will give you an error unless the j has defined before, it does not equals to     `int i = 0; int j = 20;`